# What are the common OCR errors with capitals?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

What are the common errors in OCR (optical character recognition) with capital letters?

E.g. FOR -> FOB

Comment: D and O might be easy to confuse...or maybe O and Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get most accurate answers, it is probably best to test this yourself with a sample of your data specific to your problem. Error rates for different character/word combinations can vary largely, depending on the input.

However, there are also a number of articles that can be found with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) that deal with OCR error correction, such as [A statistical approach to automatic OCR error correction in context](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/W/W96/W96-0108.pdf). Although that particular article is not capital letter specific, they discuss a few common cases of misclassification.